# SEO while using hyphen in domain name

Tags: seo, domains, google-search

I want a domain name for my website with the name sampletext.com (as an example, with sample and text being 2 words). I have the option of taking the domain names sampletext.com and sample-text.com, but my **objective is that whenever someone searches either sampletext or "sample(space)text", my website should show up in the search.** To fulfill this objective, do you think it is better to have sample-text.com as my domain name?

Comment: It does not matter one whit! Pick the one you like and you think people will use. Cheers!!